# How can I dynamically call this script that holds stuff needed to build the page and allow it to run just once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

The script holds some vars and does some jQuery stuff. I need it to run when the page is loaded which it does properly.

However, when someone clicks on a link on the originally loaded/created page, goes to that linked page (external but jQuery Mobile), and hits the back button (browser's or in the mobile page's header), the script runs again.

I don't want that behavior since it is unnecessary to rebuild the page—so I get a performance hit.

Here's how I load the script:

```
url = $.url();
rawterm = url.param('t').toLowerCase();
term = decodeURIComponent(rawterm).replace(/\+/g, " ");


var script=document.createElement('script');
script.type='text/javascript';
script.src= rawterm + ".js";
$("body").append(script);
```

The script that is called/created has stuff like this:

```
tagLimit = 200;

var myName = rawterm;
var myKey = "somekey"
var updatePage = "mtl_u_master.html?t=" + myName;
var tagSearchPage = "mtl_s_master.html?t=" + myName;
var newestPage = "mtl_n_master.html?t=" + myName;


$('#searchPage').attr('href',tagSearchPage);
$('#updatePage').attr('href',updatePage);
$('#newestPage').attr('href',newestPage);
```

Open to any and all alternate apporaches.  Thanks!

Comment: Each page is mostly independent so to do this you'd need to look at this kind of thing which works from one page  http://backbonetutorials.com/examples/modular-backbone/ Hopefully someone will provide a better explanation!

Answer (score 2):

When you say :

> However, when someone clicks on a link on the originally
>   loaded/created page, goes to that linked page (external but jQuery
>   Mobile),

do you mean you are using rel="external". If you do then there's no help because rel="external" is causing a full page refresh and I am not talking about the data-role="page" refresh, this will be a full web page refresh. When you return to the original page everything will be executed again including your script but that should not be a problem because everything your script did the first time is now gone (including page DOM).

More about this can be found here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-links.html

In case you are not using rel="external" (and remember rel="external" should be used only to load a page from the other domain) your problem can be solved easily. You just need to use a mobileinit event, like this:

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
    alert('Executed only once');
});
```

This event will be executed only and only once and it must be placed before script tag that loads jQuery mobile js, like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />     
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
    alert('Executed only once');
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

or like this:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="custom-scripting.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

More about this can be found here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Comment: Thanks! Will start some testing.

Comment: First glitch. I'm parsing the url with a script (jquery.url.js) to get the url var in the example. So, that needs to execute first. How?